# Tiled2Unity pink prefab in unity 5

Tags: unity3d-2dtools, tiled, unity-game-engine

I am using `Tiled` to make maps in an easy way then using `Tiled2Unity` to export to my unity 5 editor. Now I have imported the package and at the end exported as instructions  given :

[image: tiled2unity]

There is no error but when I go to `Tiled2Unity` folder in my **assets** and then go to prefab I get this pink prefab of my map

[image: Pink prefab]

Now I am not able to understand why I am getting this pink prefab ??

How to remove this error and get normal prefab ?

Comment: There are 2 parts to Tiled2Unity: 1) The Tiled2Unity utility that exports the map and 2) The Unity scripts that import the map and build a prefab from it.

When you say there is no error you are talking about the export tool. However, there is at least one error with importing. If you look at the bottom edge of your picture you'll see a "Failed to read Tiled2Unity import version" error along the status bar. It's possible looking for all errors in your Unity's Console window will provide more information but my guess is there is something wrong with the installation of Unity scripts.

Comment: I just solved the problem by going to shader and making it sprite default from default tiled 2 unity !

Comment: You shouldn't have to do that. If any of the Tiled2Unity shaders have errors in them for you then I'd like to know so that I can fix it for other users.